# ValueError No handler Django Channels Chat app

Tags: python, django, websocket, channel

I'm creating a chat application that some people can chat to each other in some rooms
and now I got this errors while sending messages:
raise ValueError("No handler for message type %s" message["type"]")
ValueError: No handler for message type chat_message
**Consumers.py**

```
import json 
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()
    async def disconnect(self):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name

        )
    async def receive(self,text_data):
        data=json.loads(text_data)
        message = data['message']
        username = data['username']
        room = data['room']
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message':message,
               'username' : username,
               'room': room ,

            }

        )
        async def chat_message(self,event):
            message=event['message']
            username=event['username']
            room=event['room']
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'message':message,
                 'username' : username,
               'room': room ,
        }))
```

**HTML TEMPLATE**

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block cont %}
<div class='rooms'>
  <p class='bolder'>Username</p>
  <p>The messages ......</p>
</div>
  <form method="post" action="."   >
    
    <div>
    <input type="text" name="content" class="input" placeholder="write here..." id="chat-message-input">
    <button class="bluebot" id="chat-message-submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form></div></div>
{% endblock %}
{% block scripts %}

{{ room.slug|json_script:"json-roomname" }}
{{ request.user.username|json_script:"json-username" }}
<script>

  const userName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json-username').textContent);
  const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json-roomname').textContent);
  const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
    'ws://'+window.location.host+'/ws/'+ roomName+ '/'
   );

   chatSocket.onmessage=function(e){
    console.log('onmessage')
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if(data.message)
    {
      let html ="<div class='rooms'>";
      html+="<p class='bolder'>"+data.username+'</p>';
      html+='<p>'+ data.message+'</p></div>';
      document.querySelector('#chat-messages').innerHTML+=html;  
}
    else{
      alert('the message was empty')
    }
  }
 chatSocket.onclose=function(e){
  console.log('onclose')
 }  
  document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick= function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
    const message= messageInputDom.value;
    chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({

      'message':message,
      'username': userName,
      'room':roomName,
    }));
    messageInputDom.value='';
  return false;
  }
</script> 
{% endblock scripts %}
```

No handler for message type chat_message